# Why some layers are not available in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, invalid-layer

I am using QGIS Desktop 3.22.5.

How can I resolve the issue with unavailable layers?

[image]

Comment: Привіт :) На жаль на цьому сайті офіційна мова спілкування - англійська. Тому рекомендую, або писати англійською відразу або перекладати через онлайн перекладач. Інакше інші користувачі (окрім мене і інших людей) тебе просто напросто не зрозуміють. Таким чином ти не зможеш отримати відповіді на своє питання.

Comment: Therefore, please keep it English ^_^

Comment: @Taras translated message : "Hi :) Unfortunately, the official language of communication on this site is English. Therefore, I recommend either writing in English immediately or translating through an online translator. Otherwise, other users (besides me and other people) simply will not understand you. This way you will not be able to get an answer to your question."

Answer (score 3):

If these layers are locally saved files, then either the filename has changed or the file saving path was changed - i.e. someone moved the file to another location. You must fix the correct file path. When you reopen QGIS, there will be a window promting you to fix this and you can paste the correct path.

Comment: Or click on the red sign next to the layer to relocate it.